# Position of notify.js box

Tags: javascript, jquery, notify

How can I adjust the distance between a notify.js box and the text it points to? I currently do

```
$.notify.defaults({ className: "error", gap: 10, autoHideDelay: 10000, arrowSize: 10 });
$('#button').notify('Hello!', {position:"bottom", globalPosition:"bottom" });
```

I thought the gap option is the one to use, but that one does not seem to work at all?